# Reporting Services and BLOBs

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, blob

A database I report on using SSRS has a column which is stored as a BLOB.  I happen to know that the BLOB contains XML (a string).

Is there any way for reporting services to extract this information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found a limited solution - builds would be welcome.

You need to use the function

```
dbms_lob.substr([fieldname], [number_of_characters], [start_position])
```

Note that [number_of_characters] appears to have a maximum value of 2000

Comment: Note, this is an Oracle specific solution

Answer (score 1):

without more details you should be able to either cast the Data in TSQL to the Appropriate type: `CAST(MyBlob As XML)` or `CAST(MyBlob as NVARCHAR(max))` assuming the type is stored in an ntext.

otherwise you may need to write some conversion code in an SSRS expression to create a calculated field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer JasonHorner - I'm just trying it out to see if I can get it to work!